# Keras Sequential: advantage of creating Tensorflow numeric_columns?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am learning about creating neural networks using Keras and running through various tutorials. In one, the model is built using a series of `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` and passing that to the Keras `Sequential` model (in this example `feat_cols` are the feature columns):

```
feature_columns = {c: tf.feature_column.numeric_column(c) for c in feat_cols}
model = Sequential([DenseFeatures(feature_columns=feature_columns.values()),
                    Dense(units=32, activation='relu',
                    Dense(units=8, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(units=1, activation='linear'])
```

In another tutorial, the initial input layer is just taken right from a `pandas` dataframe converted into a numpy array by using `.values`. The dictionary of tensors is never created, and the first layer doesn't have the `DenseFeatures` bit. (In this case `df` is the dataframe, `features` is a list of feature columns and `lbl` is the target column)

```
x = df[features].values
y = df[lbl].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.05)

model = Sequential([
            Dense(10, input_shape=(6, ), activation='relu'),
            Dense(20, activation='relu'),
            Dense(5, activation='relu'),
            Dense(1)])
```

In this case when `model.fit` is called, just `x_train` and `y_train` are passed instead of the tensor dict in the first example.

My question is what is the advantage or disadvantage (if any) of these two approaches? Are they two ways of getting to the same place or is there an actual difference?

Comment: Note that the sequential nets are definitely not equivalent. But if you consider only the input components, they would be essentially the same. Both are valid ways to pass your data into the net. However in practice, dataframes are more common data sources, and tensors are slightly easier to handle with Tensorflow. With the keras API however there should be no performance difference. See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe

Comment: Yes I was speaking solely of the input layer, so this answers my question exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonChia you want to post that as an aswer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequential nets are definitely not equivalent. But if you consider only the input components, they would be essentially the same. Both are valid ways to pass your data into the net. However in practice, dataframes are more common data sources, and tensors are slightly easier to handle with Tensorflow. With the keras API however there should be no performance difference. See tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe